# working with android NFC using emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator, nfc, genymotion

I am going to develop an android application for transferring some data between two devices. I am wondering whether I can use emulator devices for developing, debugging and testing this app or I need to use two real devices?

Comment: my suggestion is to use real device. Emulator doesn't support i guess so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with emulator. So trying to purchase Real Device with `NFC` Support.

Or go to this [Android Emulator with NFC Support](http://www.vegaasen.com/blog/?p=647)